# Detect "Illegal reflective access" in Unit Test

Tags: java

I'm working on a software project that currently produces `WARNING: Illegal reflective access by Classname` warnings from the Java (9+) process because it does reflective access to classes in `java.base`.

Instead of adding opens for `java.base`, I want to change the implementation to not rely on reflective access into `java.base` anymore.

I would like to guard this implementation change by a JUnit test that fails if an illegal reflective access occurs.

**What's the most elegant way to programmatically detect an illegal reflective access in a unit test?**

I have considered but rejected the following approaches:

- capturing stdout and stderr in the test (that didn't work)
- starting a separate VM in the test and checking the output (that is pretty involved)

Comment: The accepted answer in the dupe suggests running with `--illegal-access=deny` - outright denying it seems like a far better strategy than hoping your unit tests cover all the illegal access cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking a look at my question. You are right that we should run with all our tests on CI with that flag to ensure that there are no hidden cases.